# SSL Handshake Failure when calling a REST service

Tags: rest, security, ssl, weblogic

In a JSF application, I am calling a REST service to obtain information.
I have configured my application to run in HTTPS in my weblogic server.
I have created my self signed certificate and configured a custom keystore in my weblogic.

When trying to call the REST service in my managed bean I am hitting below error

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: [
Security:090477]Certificate chain received from <myproxy> - <myip> --> <externalsite> was not trusted causing SSL handshake failure.
```

I am passing thru a network proxy but I am just not sure how to fix this error.

Anyone have idea how to fix this?
Thanks

**UPDATE**

I am not sure but I am using a custom keystore in my weblogic.
Is there a way to get the certificate of the external REST service so that I can install it in my keystore?  If so how to do this.
Maybe this could fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

I use a handy utility called KeyStore Explorer (http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/). Open your custom keystore in KeyStore Explorer then use the Examine SSL option to import the certificate directly from the external site to your keystore.